# Filter out question with user involvement from the close queue

Tags: feature-request, review

AFAIK the close queue is meant to gather community opinion, but i seem to get questions which I have an answer on.

I think people are not objective if they were involved in the question, and those question should be automatically filtered out of their queue.

Comment: Well, you could learn to be objective - I can answer a question and still vote to close or delete it. It's only a small hurdle to get your mind around.

Comment: @slugster I believe I am, the question is "are everybody?".

Comment: @slugster why answer it if you think it should be closed? I've seen this happen a lot of times with questions that should be marked as duplicate. People will rather respond quickly to get points than to flag it.

Comment: @Matsemann Because it can still be answered. I don't feed the trolls, however if I can help then I will. In any case, is conflict of interest really an issue for these questions, considering how small the chances are that you would get a question you've answered? Is the reviewer really conflicted at all, considering they have indicated by answering that they think it should remain open? To summarise, **is there really a problem**, or is it an imagined one?

Comment: @slugster if you keep to specific tags both on answering and reviewing the odds are not that small. And if answers indicate that people want the question open, then answered question shouldn't be voted on.

Comment: @I3arnon It's a *community* decision, and that (potentially conflicted) reviewer is still a member of that community. Answers on closed questions can still be voted on (the answerer can still gather positive or negative rep regardless of what input they have into the review). My point is that wile you've stated a theoretical problem, you haven't actually shown if its having a negative impact on the site.

Comment: He's a part of the community even when the question is his, but I wouldn't let him vote on his own question.

Comment: I knew you were going to bring that one up... personally I differentiate between the two because they are subtly different. By eliminating the OP from the review you are eliminating one person - what happens when there are 10 answers, would you eliminate them all from the review? (I know you probably would). At some stage it has been decided not to exclude those who answer (because it is active for OPs, so it's unlikely that it wasn't discussed by the team). Once again, has there been a negative impact on the site due to this?

Comment: Understand that I'm not saying that you're wrong (some will be conflicted), I'm simply querying whether there is an actual issue or just a perceived one.

Comment: just a perceived one

Comment: I perceive this to be an issue -- if a rep whore got a lot of reputation from a bad post and wanted it to stay, they're more likely to vote "leave open" and allow poor quality questions to stay on this site. Of course, you might find that your opinion differs on this.